# How to update the child component value on change?

Tags: angular

since I am using spread operator, my changes not reflecting to child component. what is the correct way to handle this?

code in child:

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  OnInit,
  SimpleChange,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  template: `
  <h1>{{Nwname}}</h1>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of updatedRows">{{item.TelephoneNo}}</li>
  </ul>
  `,
  styles: [],
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() Nwname;
  @Input() Nwrows;
  updatedRows;
  ngOnInit() {
    const rows = [...this.Nwrows];
    this.updatedRows = rows; //updateds only once
  }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-dzotpu?file=src/app/child.componet.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example, you are assigning a new array to this.rows, so that will trigger change detection, I think your problem is that you are overring the main dataset, can try the below code

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  rows;
  dataset = [
    {
      AbbottPersonnel: 'Daavid Malan',
      TelephoneNo: '123',
      ActivationStatus: 'Inactive',
    },
    {
      AbbottPersonnel: 'Sharon Grant',
      TelephoneNo: '122',
      ActivationStatus: 'Active',
    },
    {
      AbbottPersonnel: 'Yegeny Kafalnikov',
      TelephoneNo: '122',
      ActivationStatus: 'Active',
    },
    {
      AbbottPersonnel: 'Masake Akase',
      TelephoneNo: '123',
      ActivationStatus: 'Active',
    },
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.rows = [...this.dataset]
  }

  updateSearch(Nwvalue) {
    if (!Nwvalue) {
      console.log('now vlaue', this.copy);
      this.rows = [...this.dataset];
      return;
    }
    const filtered = this.dataset.filter((record) => {
      return Object.values(record).some((value) => value.includes(Nwvalue));
    });
    console.log('filtered', filtered);
    this.rows = filtered;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Stash, it's not working. can you update my fiddle?

Comment: I updated the answer, can you try the new app component code?

Comment: Bro, use ngOnChanges or, better yet, an observable with async pipe

Comment: I think the problem is in the logic of updateSearch method

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with using spread or not. I would also suggest against forcing change detection.

Your issue is that you don't have `ngOnChanges` set up. So NgOnInit fires only once, as it should. If you want it to respond to changes in the Input then implement `OnChanges`

Code:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('On Changes: ', changes);

    if (changes && changes.rows && changes.rows.currentValue) {
      this.localRows = changes.rows.currentValue;
    }
  }
```

if for some reason above complains about using the . approach to changes, then you can also do `changes['rows']`. Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uks7uf?file=src/app/child/child.component.ts

I suggest you also look into the different Angular life cycle hooks like OnInit, AfterViewInit, etc.

Comment: I agree. can you please post the updated code. finding difficult to integrate

Comment: Make sure your component also explicitly implements with implements OnChanges